# Windows 7 HDTV oriented theme?

Tags: windows-7, themes, aero, hdtv

I have a dedicated media computer that is hooked up to a 46" LED TV. The problem is when I'm trying to use the computer from the couch, the 1920x1080 resolution makes everything tiny. I'm trying to find theme or a way to increase the relative size of icons and Windows interface (DPI ?) as to accommodate a PC hooked to a HDTV without degrading it's resolution? I've found that left clicking and scrolling will enlarge the icons but the task bar, start menu, and, file system are still very small. Basically I'm looking for a seeing impaired version of Windows.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit your Window key, type "`Display`" into the search box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  On the window that opens, choose the radio button option for "`Larger - 150%`", click `Apply`, and then log off and back on.

Comment: Genius! I was using remote desktop before and all the options had been grayed out. But this is exactly was I needed, Thank you.